# Cordova 3.4.0 navigator.camera.getPicture does not callback onSuccess or onFail for Android 4.3

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova 3.4 with Camera Plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md)

When I call

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: window.Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        //allowEdit: true,
        //cameraDirection: window.Camera.Direction.FRONT,
        //encodingType: window.Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        //targetWidth: 100,
        //targetHeight: 100,
        //popoverOptions: window.CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    alert(imageData);
}
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

this code works for Windows Phone 8.1 but does not work for Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean). When I step into code in eclipse I can see that it successfully saves photo under android temp directory but does not call JavaScript success or fail event on complete, that's why I cannot get image on android.

I both tried on Galaxy Note 2 real device and emulator and did not call onSuccess on both.

Is there any known issues or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653961/cordova-plugin-callback-received-after-second-plugin-call. Do you start your application in fullscreen mode?

Comment: @Teoman Is this issue fixed? I am also facing the same issue with cordova 3.5

Comment: are you solved this issue..

Comment: @Aravin I believe it is not resolved yet because I see people has problem with cordova 3.5. Anyway I dropped using PhoneGap anymore I am switching gear to native & xamarin, hope Cordova will make a release to fix this problem.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Thanks for your reply...i solved this issue ...using this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809164/navigator-camera-getpicture-callback-doesnt-execute-until-2nd-call/26166831#26166831

Comment: With cordova 5.1 & camera plugin 1.1.2 I am having same issue with Jelly Bean 4.4.2 & 4.4.4 still no clue how to fix this issue. Here is my post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808733/cordova-navigator-camera-getpicture-not-working-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this options:

```
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
sourceType: source
mediaType: media
```

Comment: what should be the values for sourceType and mediaType? anything valid?

Comment: source: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM    media: navigator.camera.MediaType.PICTURE

Comment: I made a try did not work, will change parameters and try again. Thanks for following up!

Comment: by the way I am trying to get picture from CAMERA not from SAVEDPHOTOALBUM

Comment: Sorry it should be camera insdead of savedphotoalbum

Comment: @PetrB not yet, I see that phonegap 3.5 is released. Hopefully it is fixed on this version.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't working, let me suggest these options. They're working as deployed on 4.2.2 (Jellybean) android and 4.4.2 (Kitkat).

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onPhotoDataSuccess, this.onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA

        });
```

//reading and appending the DOM

```
onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }
```

This will return a base64 encoded image.

Comment: Is your cordova provisions for phone allowing access to your phone?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, I had this very same issue. It turned out that I was calling "navigator.camera.cleanup()" in the Cordova "pause" event of the app (so it would clean up resources when the app was sent to the background). The problem here was that the camera sends the app to the background, so apparently calling cleanup was breaking things.