# cordova navigator.camera.getPicture not working in android

Tags: android, cordova, adb, file-transfer, telerik-appbuilder

**navigator.camera.getPicure function not working.  Its callback function never gets fired in below code. This function is from cordova camera plugin.**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
                            uploadPhoto,
                            function(message) {
                                alert('Failed to get a picture. Please select one.');
                            }, {
                                quality         : 50,
                                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                sourceType      : Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
                            });
```

In the above code uploadPhoto callback function never gets fired. And there is no traces of it in chrome dev tools console when the above function is called it opens the file selection window and after the image is selected for upload it simply returns, and then the screen gets refreshed.

**Update 6/26**
After more testing noticed that this behavior different between two different android devices one with Jelly bean version 4.4.2 and other Jelly bean version 4.4.4. In the device running with 4.4.4 navigator.camera.getPicture was successfully called but struck at file transfer. The device running Jelly bean 4.4.2 has just failed at navigator.camera.getPicture without calling its success or error callback functions which is where I struck since few days.  Looks like the cordova 5.1 with camera plugin 2.2.0 does not work with Jelly Bean or few of its versions. Maybe I will need to find cordova version & the cordova camera plugin version that works on Jelly Bean.

**Update 6/25**
Migrated the code from Telerik AppBuilder to PhoneGap. PhoneGap uses Cordova 5.1 and  configured latest Camera Plugin 2.2.0, however issue is still the same. Not sure if this issue is same as in this [**post**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10825) quite interesting this issue is not listed in [**release notes**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md), I tested in different android versions it did not work. And atleast no response to the ticket raised in Telerik Premium support so far.

**Update 6/23 1:28IST**
As suggested by Devid, followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809164/navigator-camera-getpicture-callback-doesnt-execute-until-2nd-call/26166831#26166831) I added below recommended fix right before the call navigator.camera.getPicture, the issue remains same.

```
if (device.platform === 'Android') {
  setInterval(function () {
     cordova.exec(null, null, '', '', [])
  }, 200);
}
```

**UPDATE: 6/23**
I checked the behavior in the console from chrome://inspect there is absolutely no trace during file upload activity. In the network tab could not find this http request. To understand where it stopped functioning I added console.log each stage within uploadFile function what I noticed was it did not trigger uploadPhoto callback function in navigator.camera.getPicture, but this call does invoked file chooser, but after file selection its callback uploadPhoto function did not trigger. Looks like the app is not having some access rights on the device.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    uploadPhoto,
    function(message) {
        rst.innerHTML = "Failed to get a picture. Please select one.";
    }, {
        quality         : 50,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/0ufdmzUw) is the catlog from ADB if at all gives some clue.

**Update 2/24-9:15AMIST**
Below is the Android manifest, is there any permission that I am missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="$AndroidVersionCode$"
          android:versionName="$BundleVersion$"
          package="$AppIdentifier$"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$"
                 android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:name=".TelerikCallbackActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The below cordova file upload code works perfect in simulator but fails when deployed in Android device.

Below is config.xml

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        version   = "2.0.0">

    <content src="index.html" />

    <!-- Whitelist docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist -->

    <!-- allow local pages -->
    <!-- <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> -->
    <access origin="*" />

    <!-- Grant certain URLs the ability to launch external applications. This
         behaviour is set to match that of Cordova versions before 3.6.0, and
         should be reviewed before launching an application in production. It
         may be changed in the future. -->
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->
</widget>
```

**Below is the client code**

```
uploadFile: function () {
    rst = document.getElementById(this.id + 'res');
    rst.innerHTML = "";
    var uploadTYPE = this.id;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        uploadPhoto,
        function(message) {
            rst.innerHTML = "Failed to get a picture. Please select one.";
        }, {
            quality         : 50,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });

    function uploadPhoto(fileURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        if (cordova.platformId == "android") {
            options.fileName += ".jpg" 
        }

        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        //options.httpMethod = "PUT";
        //options.contentType = 'multipart/form-data';
        var params = new Object();
        params.uid = localStorage.getItem("FOSCode");
        params.utyp = uploadTYPE;
        options.params = params; 

        options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };
        //options.httpMethod = 'POST';
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        rst.innerHTML = "Upload in progress...";
        ft.upload(
            fileURI,
            encodeURI("https://www.kinrep.com/foster/upload.php"),
            onFileUploadSuccess,
            onFileTransferFail,
            options, true);

        function onFileUploadSuccess (result) {
           // rst.innerHTML = "Upload successful";
            console.log("FileTransfer.upload");
            console.log("Code = " + result.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + result.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + result.bytesSent);
            console.log("Link to uploaded file: https://www.kinrep.com/foster/ws/contentlibrary/" + result.response);
            var response = result.response;
            var destination = "https://www.kinrep.com/foster/WS/ContentLibrary/" + response.substr(response.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
            if(this.id == 'uploadcheque') {
                document.getElementById("hdnchequeimgpath").value = destination;

            } else if(this.id == 'uploaddoorlock') {

                document.getElementById("hdndoorlockedimgpath").value = destination;
            } else {

                document.getElementById("hdnothersimgpath").value = destination;
            }
            rst.innerHTML = "File uploaded to: " +
                                                          destination + 
                                                          "</br><button class=\"button\" onclick=\"window.open('" + destination + "', '_blank', 'location=yes')\">Open Location</button>";
            //document.getElementById("downloadedImage").style.display="none";
        }

        function onFileTransferFail (error) {

            rst.innerHTML = "File Transfer failed: " + error.code;
            alert(rst.innerHTML);
            console.log("FileTransfer Error:");
            console.log("Code: " + error.code);
            console.log("Source: " + error.source);
            console.log("Target: " + error.target);
        }
    }
```

From the logcat I could not trace anything from my app after reproducing the error. Android just simply does not do anything on file upload activity from my app. The same activity works perfect from simulator.

Comment: Are you able to access this link - "https://www.kinrep.com" from your mobile browser first?

Comment: Yes. The site can access from via browser from device

Comment: Have you tried deugging it using chrome devtools? If not can you post the result here so that we can help you.
Here's a guide to do this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: @Naga Could you post your complete code in git for testing? As Devid, mentioned there should be some error in the console if you debug it using inspect devices option in chrome.

Comment: @Devid, I had viewed the log through ADB which didnot give any clue. Will use chrome devtools as suggested & update the results in this post.

Comment: @Gandhi, the file transfer code which uses cardova file transfer plugin which i posted here is almost there

Comment: I think the problem bay regard <access origin="*" />. That rule should allow everything, but if for any reason the server is not correctly whitelisted you may get a js warning/error that is not visible in the logcat. 
Nice to hear that :) Chrome DevTools are amazing, you'll love them. Please notify me with a comment here if you have any news.

Comment: @Naga When you say "Android just simply does not do anything on file upload activity from my app." Its not making the server call at all? or its getting into error callback atleast?

Comment: @Naga which version android in simulator and which version in mobile, let us know

Comment: @Devid since then could not access the tablet from PC, looks like drivers problem, working with vendor today.

Comment: @Naveen, android version in mobile is 4.4.2 not sure which version simulator is using. Will have to find from telerik.

Comment: @Gandhi, it is attempting server call but that is getting rejected. is neither getting into ajax success or error callback functions, not quite sure how to catch such exception

Comment: @Devid chrome://inspect not listing the device I am able to just access USB mass storage from PC, but while USB debugging is ON the drive is not accessible. What am i missing?

Comment: @Naga Try (re-)enabling usb debugging in settings>dev options while your device is connected. Then if you execute "adb devices" in your terminal you should see your device in the list. NB: When you run that command your device may prompt a message to allow usb debugging from your pc. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Naga Without debugging using inspect devices and getting the console logs its difficult to narrow down the problem. Try to follow step by step as mentioned in the link - 
Have you tried deugging it using chrome devtools? If not can you post the result here so that we can help you. Here's a guide to do this developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging You should be able to see your device for debugging

Comment: @Devid finally got USB debugging working. Please refer to question details updated at the end.

Comment: @Gandhi I followed the link as Devid suggested.

Comment: @Naga Well done! Mmm, which is your cordova version? 

PS: where are you from? I'm curious to know your timezone :D

Comment: @Naga I've found some other people having your problem. Many of them say this solution works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26166831/4695325

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Devid cardova.android.js build label is PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '3.6.4'; I am from India :)

Comment: @Devid I followed the link you suggested issue remains same. updated details in the question. pl. refer.

Comment: Thanks everyone & Thanks Devid your suggestions helped narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Naga Well done! Can you post your solution to help other people that will have the same problem?
Also I'm curious about what was going on :D

Comment: @Devid still working on it, I am now thinking to upgrade cordova 3.4 to 6 as people experienced same annoying issue with 3.4 not sure why telerik appwizard distributing this cardova version when such blocker exists, I have raised ticket with that folks yet to hear from them in 12 more hrs :)

Comment: Should have opted Phone Gap open source instead Telerik AppWizard, what is the point when service is so poor...

Comment: Updating all my findings in question hoping it may help someone..

Comment: Have you added Camera Permission??? on which device(OS Version) are you working??

Comment: @PramodWaghmare yes this code works in Android version 5 and above, but does not work in below version

Answer (score 2):

Okay, since no one answered my question posted since 12 days, decided to answer my own question. After various findings on this issue across the net. I found there is one community which is test certifying cordova builds across the devices. In their website it is clearly documented that there are issues with cordova-camera-plugin with Android devices. Below is what is mentioned at their [**website**](http://taco.tools/docs/validated-kits.html)

> **cordova-plugin-camera (version 1.0.1). The camera fails many of our tests on Samsung devices running Jellybean, Kitkat, and Lollipop. We noticed various other issues across iOS and Windows Phone 8 as well. Because of these issues, we will not be including the camera as a part of this kit.**

There are some suggested workarounds which I also referred in my question, but unfortunately those did not work on Jelly Bean platforms I am testing with right now.

And hence so the logical conclusion is to develop & build the native app using Android SDK in Android studio instead wasting time & energy in finding a fix for cordova-camera-plugin. I know this may not be ideal but I think this is how to deal with at this point of time. Hope this answer saves time to some who experience similar issues

Looks like corodva camera plugin works with latest android 6.x versions. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10857 But this will not work for my case where my users are still with old android versions. This would be the only choice when file transfers wont work even in native SDK code, but that is quite unlikely the case.

Comment: Hi Naga, I am facing the same issue with phonegap Camera which I use with Kendo UI, after upgrading to KendoUICore 2019.3.1023, android build is not saving the images and also not uploading the same.